# How to generate rectangles considering only a percentage area of a base object?

Tags: postgis, polygon-creation

I am trying to generate a rectangle by considering a small percentage of area of the extent of a geometry object in the PostGIS.

I have tried to use the ST_Scale function. It successfully generates a rectangle that corresponds to 0.01% of area of the extent of my geometry by using the following command:

```
select st_area(st_scale((select st_envelope(geom) from tab limit 1), 0.01, 0.01, 0.01)), 
st_area((select st_envelope(geom) from tab limit 1));
```

As response I got:

--0.152626509356218;1526.26509356218 = 0.0001 = 0.01% of the area

However, for 0.1%, 0.5% and other percentages it does not work. Is there other way to generate these rectangles?

I need to generate rectangles that have 0.1%, 0.5%, and 1% of area of the extent of a given geometry.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @John When I use the following command to 0.5%: select st_area(st_scale((select st_envelope(geom) from tab limit 1), 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), st_area((select st_envelope(geom) from tab limit 1)); it gives me the following result: 3.81566273390544;1526.26509356218, which corresponds to 0,25%..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST_Scale takes scale factors for each dimension, and not a percentage for the area. This means you cannot simply expect to use 0.01 and expect to see 0.01% of the area.

Area has dimensional units [length] x [length], so a scale applied to each of these dimensions will raised to the power of 2. Therefore, you need to apply a `sqrt(scale)`.

For example, here is a Polygon envelope that is scaled to 0.01% of the area:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Scale(ST_Envelope(geom), length_scale, length_scale, length_scale))
     / ST_Area(ST_Envelope(geom)) * 100 AS percent_area
FROM (
    SELECT sqrt(0.01 / 100) AS length_scale
) s, (
    SELECT 'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'::geometry AS geom
) tab;
 percent_area
--------------
         0.01
(1 row)
```

You can see that the `0.01` in the SQL statement and result are the same. You may expect some small floating point precision errors on real-world data.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I forgot about the dimensional units of area =)